# Python Sudoku Solver

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sudoku

I wrote this program for a Sudoku solver in Python. It utilizes `tkinter` GUI. I've uploaded the project to my [GitHub](https://github.com/MGedney1/Sudoku_Solver).

Please can you have a look and let me know of any ideas or improvements you think I should make?

```py
from tkinter import Frame,Entry,Button,messagebox

class app(Frame):
    def __init__(self):     #Initialising
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.create_grid()      #Creating the sudoku grid
        self.create_buttons()       #Creating the reset and solve buttons


    def create_grid(self):
        self.cells = {}       #Creating a dict for the cells in the grid
        self.tableheight = 9
        self.tablewidth = 9
        counter = 0
        for row in range(self.tableheight):     #Iterating through the rows and columns creating entries
            for col in range(self.tablewidth):
                self.cells[counter] = Entry(self,width=5,justify='center')      #Creating the Entry
                if (counter % 3==2):        #Creating extra vertical breaks to split into 3x3 boxes
                    pad_x = (3,10)
                else:
                    pad_x = 3

                if ((counter // 9) == 2) or ((counter // 9) == 5):      #Creating extra horizontal breaks to split into 3x3 boxes
                    pad_y = (3,10)
                else:
                    pad_y = 3

                if (counter % 9) == 0:      #Extra space to the sides of the board
                    pad_x = (25,3)
                elif (counter % 9) == 8:
                    pad_x = (3,25)

                if (counter // 9) == 0:
                    pad_y = (25,3)
                elif (counter // 9) == 8:
                    pad_y = (3,25)


                self.cells[counter].grid(row=row,column=col,padx=pad_x,pady=pad_y)      #Setting in a grid and adding padding
                counter+=1

        self.master.bind('<Up>',self.up)        #Key bindings to move between cells
        self.master.bind('<Left>',self.left)
        self.master.bind('<Right>',self.right)
        self.master.bind('<Down>',self.down)

    def up(self,event):
        current_cell = str(self.focus_get())[12:]       #Splitting the string of default entry names to get the number
        if len(current_cell) == 0:      #Naming started with no number at the end so setting to 1
            current_cell = '1'
        current_cell = int(current_cell) - 1        #Getting the current cell index
        row = current_cell//9       #Finding the row the cell is on
        if row == 0:        #Getting new row
            new_row = 8
        else:
            new_row = row -1
        next_cell = new_row*9 + (current_cell % 9)      #Getting index of target cell       
        self.cells[next_cell].focus_set()       #Setting focus to new entry 

    def left(self,event):
        current_cell = str(self.focus_get())[12:]       #Splitting the string of default entry names to get the number
        if len(current_cell) == 0:      #Naming started with no number at the end so setting to 1
            current_cell = '1'
        current_cell = int(current_cell) - 1        #Getting the current cell index
        if (current_cell == 0):     #Index of new entry
            next_cell = 80
        else:
            next_cell = current_cell - 1
        self.cells[next_cell].focus_set()       #Setting focus to new entry 

    def right(self,event):
        current_cell = str(self.focus_get())[12:]       #Splitting the string of default entry names to get the number
        if len(current_cell) == 0:      #Naming started with no number at the end so setting to 1
            current_cell = '1'
        current_cell = int(current_cell) - 1        #Getting the current cell index
        if (current_cell == 80):        #Index of new entry
            next_cell = 0
        else:
            next_cell = current_cell + 1        
        self.cells[next_cell].focus_set()       #Setting focus to new entry 

    def down(self,event):
        current_cell = str(self.focus_get())[12:]       #Splitting the string of default entry names to get the number
        if len(current_cell) == 0:      #Naming started with no number at the end so setting to 1
            current_cell = '1'
        current_cell = int(current_cell) - 1        #Getting the current cell index
        row = current_cell//9       #Finding the row the cell is on
        if row == 8:        #Getting new row
            new_row = 0
        else:
            new_row = row + 1
        next_cell = new_row*9 + (current_cell % 9)      #Getting index of target cell       
        self.cells[next_cell].focus_set()       #Setting focus to new entry 

    def create_buttons(self):       #Creating buttons
        self.reset = Button(self,text='Reset',command=self.reset_values)        #Reset
        self.reset.grid(row=11,column=1)    
        self.solve = Button(self,text='Solve',command=self.solve_sudoku)        #Solve
        self.solve.grid(row = 11, column=7)


    def reset_values(self):     #Reset entries
        for counter in range(81):
            self.cells[counter].delete(0,'end')
            self.cells[counter].configure(fg='black')

    def check_values(self):     #Checks cell values are allowed
        self.fetch_values ()        #Fetching values
        self.cells_given = 0
        for x in self.cells_list:       #Checking the number of cells intially filled is greater than 17 to allow for unique solution
            if x != 0:
                self.cells_given += 1
        if (self.cells_given < 17):         #Less than 17 enteries results in non unique solution
            messagebox.showwarning('Non Unique Solution','Entering less that 17 initial cells means the solution can not be unique')
        self.different_values_given = len(list(set(self.cells_list)))       #Getting length of the list of unique cell values given
        if self.different_values_given < 9:     #Checking the number of different values given is greater than 9 (8 for unique sudoku but this also counts 0)
            messagebox.showwarning('Non Unique Solution','Entering less than 8 different intial values means the solution can not be unique.')
        self.convert_to_board()     #Getting the list of cell values in a board format
        for row in range(9):        #iterating through each cell
            for col in range(9):
                value = self.board[row][col]
                if value!=0:
                    if (self.check_valid(row,col,value)):     #Check for violations of sudoku rules at start
                        print(row,col)
                        messagebox.showerror('Entry Error','Initial board contains violation of Sudoku rules')

    def fetch_values(self):     #Gets cell values from board
        self.cells_list = list(self.cells.values())     #Getting the cell values as a list
        for x in range(81):
            self.cells_list[x] = self.cells_list[x].get()
            if (self.cells_list[x] not in ['','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']):  #Checking the cell values are allowed
                messagebox.showerror('Value Error','Please ensure all enteries are between 1-9.\nLeave empty cells blank.')
                self.reset_values()
                raise Sudoku_Error()
            if (self.cells_list[x] == ''):      #Converting empty cells to 0s
                self.cells_list[x] = '0'
                self.cells[x].configure(fg='blue')
            self.cells_list[x] = int(self.cells_list[x])        #Converting cell values from strings to integers

    def convert_to_board(self):     #Converting from a list length 81 to list of 9 lists length 9
        self.board = [] 
        for iteration in range(9):  #Iterating through different rows
            row = []
            for pos in range(iteration*9,(iteration+1)*9):      #Iterating through different columns in the set row
                row.append(self.cells_list[pos])        #Appending to the current rows list
            self.board.append(row)      #Appending row list to the board

    def check_valid(self,row,col,value):        #Checking if a test value is valid

        row_valid = all([value != x for x in self.board[row]])#grid[row][x] for x in range(9)])      #Check if value violates row condition
        col_valid = all([value != self.board[y][col] for y in range(9)])      #Check if value violates column condition

        if not(row_valid and col_valid):        #Returning false unless value is valid for both row and column constraints
            return False

        box_start_row,box_start_col = 3*(row//3),3*(col//3)       #Finding the position values for top left of the 3x3 box which the current test cell resides in

        for y in range(box_start_row,box_start_row + 3):        #Checking if test value violates box condition
            for x in range(box_start_col,box_start_col + 3):
                if self.board[y][x] == value:
                    return False

        return True

    def solve_sudoku(self):        #Solving
        self.check_values()     #Checking intitial 
        self.solve_initial()        #Initial solving algorithm
        self.publish_answer()       #Publishing results


    def solve_initial(self):
        repeat = False      #Setting a variable to repeat if grid was changed this iteration
        for row in range(9):
            for col in range(9):
                if self.board[row][col] == 0:
                    possible_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]       #Setting possible values before other cell's value contraints

                    row_values = [self.board[row][x] for x in range(9)]       #Getting values from the cells row
                    col_values = [self.board[y][col] for y in range(9)]       #Getting values from the cells column
                    box_values = []
                    box_start_row,box_start_col = 3*(row//3),3*(col//3) 
                    for y in range(box_start_row,box_start_row + 3):        #Getting values from the cells box
                        for x in range(box_start_col,box_start_col + 3):
                            box_values.append(self.board[y][x])

                    restricted_values = row_values + col_values + box_values        #Combining to get the total list of values not allowed
                    restricted_values = list(set(restricted_values))        #Removing duplicates

                    restricted_values.remove(0)     #Have to remove 0 as that isnt a possible value for completed suduko

                    for value in restricted_values:     #Removing the restricted values from the possible value list
                        possible_values.remove(value)

                    if len(possible_values) == 1:       #If only one possible value, set that value and set repeat to true
                        self.board[row][col] = possible_values[0]
                        repeat = True

        if repeat:      #Repeating if repeat is true
            self.solve_initial()        


        if (self.solve_brute()):      #If not repeating attempt brute force to check if solved and if not then finish
            return

    def solve_brute(self,row = 0,col = 0):        #Solve function with inital params for row and col set

        row, col = self.next_cell(row,col)

        if (row == -1) and (col == -1):     #If no more cells to solve, return completed grid
            return True

        for value in range(1,10):
            if self.check_valid(row,col,value):
                self.board[row][col] = value      #Updating the cell to the new value if it is valid

                if self.solve_brute(row,col):     
                    return True
                self.board[row][col] = 0      #Reset the current cell to unfilled for backtracking
        return False

    def next_cell(self,row,col):        #Finding the next cell to fill
        for y in range(row,9):      #Check grid from min row col values for unfilled cells (treating 0 as unfilled)
            for x in range(col,9):
                if self.board[y][x] == 0:
                    return y,x
        for y in range(9):      #Check entire grid for unfilled cells
            for x in range(9):
                if self.board[y][x] == 0:
                    return y,x
        return -1,-1        #Returns -1,-1 if all cells filled

    def publish_answer(self):
        self.answer_cells = []
        for y in range(9):
            for x in range(9):
                self.answer_cells.append(self.board[y][x])
        for pos in range(81):
            if (self.cells_list[pos] == 0):
                self.cells[pos].insert(0,self.answer_cells[pos])


class Sudoku_Error(Exception):
    pass   


prog = app()
prog.master.title('Sudoku Solver')
prog.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

I strongly feel that you should separate the logic of the graphics and the algorithm of solving the sudoku. The algorithm is just some operation defined on some data structure of your choosing (actually a good way to regard solving sudokus is as extending a colouring of a graph).

I would write this algorithm to act on whatever data structure is most convenient and makes the algorithm as evident as possible.

Then have functions to adapt between the algorithm representation and the board internal representation.

Then have functions which take you from the boards internal representation to the GUI representation.

Answer (score 1):

## Class Names

Classes should be in `PascalCase`, not `lowercase`. So your class should be `App`.

## Operator Spacing

There should be a space before and after every operator (`+-*/=`, etc) in your program. It improves the readability of your code greatly.

## Comments

When commenting, it's common to put them a line before, so the reader sees the comment then the preceding line of code that the comment addresses. Inline comments, especially when really long like yours, are unnecessary.

## `check_valid`

You can greatly simplify how you check a valid sudoku board. Using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), it will return True if any of the element in the iterator are True. But in this case, since you want all `False` values to be checked, simply do `not any(...)`. Take a look:

```
def check_valid(self,row,col,value):

    row_valid = all([value != x for x in self.board[row]])
    col_valid = all([value != self.board[y][col] for y in range(9)])

    if not(row_valid and col_valid):
        return False

    box_start_row, box_start_col = 3 * (row // 3), 3 * (col // 3)

    return not any(
        self.board[y][x] == value
        for y in range(box_start_row, box_start_row + 3)
        for x in range(box_start_col, box_start_col + 3)
    )
```

## Contants

I see you've defined `self.tableheight` and `self.tablewidth` as constants (although they should be `snake_case` then `UPPER_CASE`). That's good. But you only use them once and never again! Then you have stray `9` values all over your code. You should utilize these class constants.